# Do iTunes or Windows Media Player affect the quality of my MP3 collection?

Tags: mp3

I have a back up directory of all my mp3 files because I am concerned about the above mentioned tools decreasing the quality of the files.

Since my collection is fairly large I find the auto-tagging, lyric add in (by plug in MiniLyrics) and  album cover finder features helpful in cleaning up this collection.

I've also used MediaMonkey but didn't find it as able to help update files but prefer it's ability to help me keep my files organized.

Will these tools deteriorate the audio quality of my files?  Is there a better way to do this?

It's 30+ gigs so manually processing everything is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends. Unless you transcode the files (which is an option with both) there should absolutely be no loss in quality. Metadata can be edited without changing the original file and is just a [chunk of data at the end of the file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3).

There are likely better ways but its a matter of getting a workflow in place - i've managed a roughly 90 gig set of files with passes with [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) and [picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard)in addition to a music player, and its all consistant, and tagged identically.

Answer (score 0):

Using iTunes or Windows Media Player to tag the files won't affect the quality of the files at all, as all they are doing is adding tagging information to the file. They usually don't do any sort of re-encoding or audio processing.